# Can no longer connect to Google Cloud VM instance through putty

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, putty

I set up a VM instance on Google Cloud and connected to it using PuTTY from my windows machine according to this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-and-connect-to-google-cloud-virtual-machine-with-ssh-81a68b8f74dd/

I was able to use it for a couple of days. However since the last 2 days I can no longer connect to it. Putty displays only blank and after a while the error "Network error: connection timed out" appears.

I have changed nothing since my previous successful connections (except my location).

Comment: A timeout usually points to a firewall issue. Check your security groups and other fields in-between.

Answer (score 0):

At first, please check logs at `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`. I'd recommend you to restart your VM instance and check the log for any error or warning messages.

After that, have a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) and follow the instructions.

If nothing helped, you can try to connect to your VM via Serial console by following this [guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b), but keep in mind that:

> The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
> restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
> serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
> instance from any IP address.

more details you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).